# COUNT empty cells from a range that's being created by an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: excel

Below the following use case:

I have a recipe table that looks like this:
[image]

I want to check the recipe against another table:
[image]

This is what I came up with in creating an intermediate result:

```
{=VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(RECIPES!$B$3:$AP$1000;MATCH(A3;RECIPES!$A$3:$A$7;0);0)‌​);INVENTORIES!$A$3:$S$1000;3;FALSE)}
```

[image]

How can I sum or count this intermediate result?

*edit*
When I try, I get this pop-up:
[image]

Comment: So you just want to count the number of `Present` in that column?

Comment: Maybe I'm getting the wrong end of the stick here but isn't it just the case of replacing `;` in your formula to `'`?. When I try to use `;` in my formula, it throws an error

Comment: As per your request, posting the same comment again as another comment: Maybe I'm getting the wrong end of the stick here but isn't it just the case of replacing ; in your formula to '?. When I try to use ; in my formula, it throws an error

Comment: Will countif not work for you?

Comment: @a-burge No, it throws an error.

Comment: Which one @JacobJanTuinstra?

Comment: @a-burge see post.

Comment: Could you provide the countif formula? This is the error you get for example if there is an off parenthesis or parameters haven't been filled correctly.

Comment: `COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(RECIPES!B3:AP3;INVENTORIES!A3:S1000;3;FALSE);0)`

Comment: It's giving you that error because there is a problem in your `VLookUp` formula. To my knowledge, you cannot look for a range in `VLookUp`. You have to specify a value that your want to look for in a range. What are you actually trying to achieve? You have 2 sheets with data and are you just trying to have a third sheet that tells you which products are in your recipe?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you add this function to the beginning of your intermediate formula:

IFERROR("Your formula","") This will take away any #NA errors.

If it is the "Present" that you are trying to count, simply use COUNTA()

Comment: Hi Tony, I'm afraid that that did bring the desired outcome? Did you try that in advance yourself?

Comment: did ==> didn't !

Comment: Hello, yes, i had tried it out but not with the same formula given as i didnt have the data to test it with. I left the if error within and counta () on the oter layer. I'll try later today to see if theres something im missoing